# Expect Send SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, send, except

I just want to loggin via ssh automatically

When i try this script the entering of the user name works perfectly
..but when the script tries to enter the password...nothing happens and after some time the script get cancled. I have definitly tried everything with the expression of the except from the password....

Can anybody help me please!?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh admin@10.101.96.2
expect '*User: '
send "admin\r"
expect 'assword:'
send "AHSa4heL.\r"
send "show interface summary"
```

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to log into `ssh` via `expect`

```
spawn bash -c "ssh user@machine"
expect "?*assword:*"
send -- "password\r"
expect "$"
```

One of the things is you have `assword:` with no regular expression to say hey expect this to say something other then `assword:` it says only expect `assword:` so it is doing what you have told expect to do. Also why do you have to input the user name again if you are doing `user@machine`? So you shouldn't in my experience expect to enter the user name again unless a customized `ssh` login expects `user` to be sent.